# Populating Combobox (Data Bound) from call not working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that has a list of 7 'handlers' from a data binding (local SQL server DB).

I am trying to pass a value into this from a call, but when i run the code, the value presented is always the first value in the list of handlers. e.g. i'll pass 'handler 4' in my call, but 'handler 1' will populate.

I've tried populating the '.Text','.SelectedText' and using a value instead of string, the '.SelectedValue', to no avail. any help here?

```
public partial class Start_Form : ICallFormBase
{
    public Start_Form()
    {

    }
    public Start_Form(Call call)
        : base(call)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Notes_text.Text = Call.Notes;
        if (call.Id > 0)
        {
            Handler.SelectedValue = Call.BeginAudit.Handlerstore;
            Audit_Date.Value = Call.BeginAudit.Auditdatestore;
            Auditor.SelectedValue = Call.BeginAudit.Auditorstore;
            ClaimRef.Text = Call.BeginAudit.Claimrefstore;
            Notes_text.Text = call.Notes;
        }
    }
}
```